# ManyToOne OneToMany JPA mapping not working right

Tags: jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

It seems I have a problem with OneToMany, ManyToOne mapping.

I'm using a CrudRepository named "ur" here:

```
ur.save(new User("zx","z", "a", "email@email.com", "Baa")); //userRepo save
User u1 = ur.findOneByUserName("Bx");
MyToken t1 = new MyToken("X5");
u1.addToken(t1);
ur.save(u1);
MyToken t2 = TokenRepo.findOneByToken("X5"); // a different crudRepository
String foundUser = t2.getUser().getUserName(); // THIS "user" is null.
```

relevant sections of User.java (extends AbstractPersistable<Long>):

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade={CascadeType.ALL}, mappedBy = "user")
private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<Role>(1);

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade={CascadeType.ALL}, mappedBy = "user")
private Set<MyToken> token = new HashSet<MyToken>();
```

MyToken.java (extends AbstractPersistable<Long>):

```
 @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
 @JoinColumn(name="user") // commenting this out or not does nothing...
    private User user;
```

My debugger says 'user' is 'null' at line "String foundUser" even though that should be completely false according to the code.

As you can see, all is "eager" so I don't see why MyToken.setUser() is not automatically done. How are they not linked already? AnyInitiatedToken.getUser() should not be null if you already did User.addToken, and UserRepo.save().

NOTE: I have also tried .LAZY for the MyToken.java and Role.java class (but still doesn't work).

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem with the code provided. See [a sample](https://github.com/manish-in-java/stackoverflow-questions/tree/master/43810658) on Github that works. Please compare and post actual code where the error is encountered.

Comment: @manish after reviewing your exampel code, what I found is that you actually mutually-add user. Token(userU, "Tx") instead of how I do it Token("Tx") and expect that User + Token combine. But maybe I need a joinTable annotation for automatic configuring.

Comment: I decided to change role to many-to-many, and keep tokens as one-to-many and include user in the constructor arguments (user u, string token.....) and everything works. Also had to remove LAZY loading due to lazy load errors after multiple "pulls" from repos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you did not post the setters, I gonna assume they look like default setter.

`User.token` is set, but it has a `mappedby`, so it is really irrelevant for what is stored in the DB. `Token.user` matters, but that is still an `NULL` so that's what get's saved and retrieved.

You have two options:

1. Change `User.setToken()` to update `Token.user` of the passed in `Token` (and of the one that was previously set.
2. Whenever you call `User.setToken()` also update `Token.users` to make both directions of the relationship match.

Comment: yes setters/getters are normal setters/getters. I don't understand your answer though, so what am I supposed to be doing so that MyToken.user is automatically filled in by setting User.token, they should be bi-directional and linked together in the Database, so shouldn't .getUser() bring the latest User linked to this MyToken?

Comment: that doesn't make much sense. You cannot put "mappedBy" on a ManyToOne and you can't just switch them like that (re #3). If I have to define "addToken" to update Token.user, or update setUser to also add User.addToken... then it's not bi-directional. What's the point of "mappedBy=user" then? When will "mappedBy=user" be useful? I can remove "mappedBy=user" and everything will work the same.

Comment: "I can remove "mappedBy=user" and everything will work the same." No, it won't, It would be two independent relationships.

Comment: "You cannot put "mappedBy" on a ManyToOne" Hmm, you are right. Darn I always thought you could.

Comment: Right the only two options seem to be manually adding logic to your "setters/getters"... or... no idea... extending CrudRepository somehow to use joins. I was sure in one of my tests that it was auto-cascading and adding roles, but even that doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not related to the fetch strategy whether it's *eager* or *lazy* fetch type. I think you gave column alias for the user's id and missed that the *name* atributte's value  of the `@JoinColumn` should reference that primary key column alias.

Like in the *User* you have:

```
@Id
@Column(name = "userid", unique = true, nullable = false)
public String getUserId() {
return this.userId;
    }
```

then in the *Token* should be

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinColumn(name="userid") // commenting this out or not does nothing...
private User user;
```

Comment: I tried this @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name="user_entity_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    private User user;   but no luck